# Turn off multiple error messages inside ngSubmit()

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using 2 methods checking is user in role of admin or user.
When I go as admin it throws user exception but logs in successfully and vice versa

My component looks like:

```
 login() {
    this.authService.login(this.model).subscribe(next => {     
        this.isAdmin = true;
        this.alertify.success('Logged in as Admin')      
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error)
    }, () => {
      this.router.navigate(['/projects'])
    })
  }

  loginAsUser() {
    this.authService.loginAsUser(this.model).subscribe(next => {     
      this.isAdmin = false;
      this.alertify.success('Logged in as User')      
  }, error => {    
    this.alertify.error(error)
  }, () => {
    this.router.navigate(['/home'])
  })
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return this.authService.loggedIn();
  }
```

HTML looks like:

```
<form *ngIf="!loggedIn()" #loginForm="ngForm" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" 
            (ngSubmit)="login();loginAsUser();">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" required 
          [(ngModel)]="model.username" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-unlock text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required type="password"
          [(ngModel)]="model.password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0">
          <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Login
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Is it any another approach to use multiple functionality in ngSubmit()?
How can I get only one message "logged in as admin" and not message "unathorized" beside it.

Comment: I think no need to execute two different methods to achieve that. You should call some API and pass the login info which will return the user is a normal user or admin and after that you can write the functionality as per role.

Comment: As backend I am using .net core and in user table I have already role which is enum and isAdmin boolean property. I tried use one method like login() and implemented logic if this.model.role == 'Admin' return true in this case I always get back else case which is role == 'User' and I tried to implement 2 seperate login functionality. I am also using jwt maybe it will be another way like save 2 another tokens for user role.But I don't know which approach I need to use

Comment: You can get the user role from the backend based on his unique login id (email or phone) right ?

Comment: Yes role according to id. For ex:  { "id":23,
        "username": "test2",
        "role": "User",
        "isAdmin": false
    },

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pKdjXP

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to store in the user table the role of each user.

In this way, you can make only one query and return the user to know if it's an admin.

There must be only one method in the ngsubmit, this method can however call several methods